# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined MongoDB.Clusters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Im trying to get data from MongoDB cluster first time.but showing error like that. I cant understand the bug.

```
mongoose
  .connect(mongoDB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

  var db = mongoose.connection;

 db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection
 error:'));



app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  res.send(db.chatApp.find());
  
});

[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Example app listening on port 5000
MongoDB Connected...
GET /home 500 4.329 ms - 2219
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```